# AppCompat v7 not being referenced properly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I'm new to Xamarin Android. I've installed the `AppCompatv7` Support Library from the `GetComponents` option.

But whenever I try and do anything with it, I get no intellisense, like it isn't actually added to the project. Like below:

[image]

When I look more into the assembly it comes up with an option like below, saying it might not be installed. But as you can see from the picture, it is installed under my references.

[image]

If I click `Add Package` in the below picture, nothing happens.

When I compile the code, it can't find functions in the `ActionBarActivity` base class, so I'm guessing it's not adding it properly into my project.

Anyone know why this is happening? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> When I compile the code, it can't find functions in the ActionBarActivity base class, so I'm guessing it's not adding it properly into my project.

`ActionBarActivity` is obsolete.

To use `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar`, after installing the [Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/) package, you can simply inherit your `MainActivity` from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity`.

Then for example my toolbar is like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbartitile"
    android:text="Kodej" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Include this toolbar in `Main` layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           layout="@layout/mytoolbar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

You just need to reference `Android.Support.V7.App` in your code:

```
using Android.Support.V7.App;
```

All references in my demo:

[image]

If you've installed the libs correctly and there is no no intellisense, you can try to rebuild your app, close and reopen your VS.

Answer (score 0):

Install it using the NuGet Command Console :

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat -Pre
```